# is it possible to make a Facebook canvas app that is not a game?

Tags: facebook

I am interested in creating a canvas app that will work as a communication tool that will use facebook user's friends lists. Is it possible to make a facebook canvas app that is actually a tool and not a game? Or is this agains facebook's policies? I couldn't find a direct answer for this question anywhere, so I thought I would ask here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can create Apps too, but you will still not get the full friend list of the user, only those who are using the App (with `/me/friends`).

You can use `taggable_friends` to tag friends, But you are not allowed to use those for something else - only for tagging.

According to the Facebook docs, `invitable_friends` is only for Games - and of course it has to be used for inviting friends only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to make sure I am getting this, if a user signs up for an app, will that user have access to all of his friends through the app?

Comment: no, that is not possible (anymore), see changelog. you can only get the friends who are using the app too with /me/friends, since v2.0. this is for privacy reasons, an app should not be able to access someone who is not even using the app.